Hosting a peerjs server on iisnode, client side unable to connect status "Finished" the status should be "101", not sure why this is happening?
So I have built a WebSocket server on ws and this works perfectly for sending basic messages.
What I wanted to do next was create a peer to peer calling service using PeerServer server side and PeerJS client side.
However the client cannot connect to the server the WebSocket keeps returning status:"Finished".
Again this is specifically iisnode.
Here is my web.config file :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="node_app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ws" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^NodeJS/WebSocket/WS/?$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="\NodeJS\WebSocket\WS\node_app.js" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="peerjs" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^NodeJS/PeerJS/Server/?.*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="\NodeJS\PeerJS\Server\node_app.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

The rule name="ws" is for the basic WebSocket server.
Server side code for PeerServer "\NodeJS\PeerJS\Server\node_app.js" :
// peer_server
var ExpressPeerServer = require('peer').ExpressPeerServer;
var peerExpress = require('express');
var peerApp = peerExpress();
var peerServer = require('http').createServer(peerApp);
var options = { debug: true }
var peerPort = process.env.PORT;

peerApp.use('/', ExpressPeerServer(peerServer, options));
peerServer.listen(peerPort);

Client side Javascript :
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var url = '/NodeJS/PeerJS/Server/'; 
    var peer_url = location.hostname + url;
    var thisCallerID = 123; 
    
    peerJS = new Peer(thisCallerID,{
        host: location.hostname,
        path: url,
        debug: 1
    });
}); 

The error log I get sever side is :

(node:17520) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was cre
ated)

However I get this warning on the WebSocket server too and it works just fine.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
##EDIT##
Client side console errors :

socket.ts:42 WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.co.za/NodeJS/PeerJS/Server?key=peerjs&id=123&token=s0gab0l3rf9&version=1.5.4' failed:


logger.ts:76 ERROR PeerJS:  Error: Lost connection to server.


"The error log I get sever side is :" That's not an error. It's a DeprecationWarning. Is your question, how to fix this issue? If yes, do you call Buffer() somewhere in your code? If not, it's a problem in your dependencies. Where does it come from?

It's still unclear what your question is, because there is no explicit question. You have a deprecation warning. If you want to fix this issue, I've described how to do it. If that's not your question, your actual question is unclear.

Is your questions answere here: DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues when I move my script to another server

@jabaa I believe this is from one of the included modules, I believe it comes from express module. However I know it is just  a warning not an error I just included the error log so that anyone looking would have all the details.
The question is that I am unable to connect to the Peer Server and I'm not sure why?

Do you see error messages in the console? Why do you think there is a problem? I've run your code and didn't see any problems.

@jabaa I've updated the Question to include the console errors.

What happens when you open location.hostname + '/NodeJS/PeerJS/Server/' in the browser?

When viewing the file directly I get a 404 but this is the same as what I get if I view the WebSocket file directly. Also on that note if I replace the code in the node_app.js file with the WebSocket code it actually dose connect however then I obviously don't have the functionality of PeerJS.

"When viewing the file directly I get a 404" That seems to be a problem, because when I start the server and open the URL in the browser, I get this message: {"name":"PeerJS Server","description":"A server side element to broker connections between PeerJS clients.","website":"https://peerjs.com/"} and HTTP status 200. I've created an example on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8utvps

So it was really quite obvious can't believe I missed this but in case someone else made this mistake too.
In the PeerJS Server file where you set the express app to use the ExpressPeerServer this takes a url path as an argument. This path needs to be the actual URL path of file, in my case "/NodeJS/PeerJS/Server/".
// peer_server
var ExpressPeerServer = require('peer').ExpressPeerServer;
var peerExpress = require('express');
var peerApp = peerExpress();
var peerServer = require('http').createServer(peerApp);
var options = { debug: true }
var peerPort = process.env.PORT;

peerApp.use('/NodeJS/PeerJS/Server/', ExpressPeerServer(peerServer, options));
peerServer.listen(peerPort);

